# Weird Editbox appearance after updating to Android Oreo

Tags: android-studio

Everything was fine with my editbox until the Oreo update and it's appearing as shown in the screenshot, I'm looking at my XML and I cant see why nor do I see anything about depreciation. Can anyone give me a hint to why it's appearing in such manner? It also shows fine in the preview but when i run it appears like that.

```
<EditText

    android:id="@+id/edtFName"
    android:hint=""
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    />
```

[image: Editbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but problem looks like  due to elevation :try to remove android:elevation attribute